# Find boost_python version from setup.py

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have developed a Python module using Boost Python. This extension has a `setup.py` file to install it. This file requests the extension to be linked against `libboost_python` by doing something like the following:

```
my_module = Extension('_mymodule', files=...
        libraries=['boost_python'],
        ...)
```

Recently, the boost developers seem to have changed the naming convention of Boost Python from naming the library `libboost_python` to naming it `libboost_python27` (to reflect the fact that they were calling `libboost_python3` the corresponding library for Python 3.x).

What is the best way, from the `setup.py` script, to detect how the Boost Python library should be named (given that it is installed in a non-standard location)?